# zendesk integration for tickets in my react + node js app

Tags: callback, integration, zendesk, zendesk-app

I want to integrate zendesk app using oauth2, user can connect zendesk account and allow my application to read data, I successfully done this for my dev account and can read tickets details, I want to make it generic that any user can connect his/her zendesk account with my app but when I use user's subdomain, doesn't work.

```
https://${subdomain}.zendesk.com/oauth/authorizations/new?client_id=${ZENDESK_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&scope=read
```

above callback works for my subdomain/account using which I created app and using client_id etc but not working for any other zendesk subdomain.

what could be the reason? am I missing any integration step?